# How to get a basename of .tar.gz file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, url

I would like to get the basename of a tar.gz file in python.

So from `"foo/bar/alice.tar.gz"` i want `alice`

What I have so far is:

```
url = "foo/bar/alice.tar.gz"

Path(Path(url).stem).stem

print(url)

~ alice
```

is there a smoother way to do so? What if my url is something like `"foo/bar/alice.tar.gz.tar.gz.tar.gz"` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

i think that will do the job:

```
>>> import os
>>> base=os.path.basename("foo/bar/alice.tar.gz")
>>> base
'alice.tar.gz'
>>> name = base.split('.')
'['alice', 'tar', 'gz']'
>>> name = base.split('.')[0]
'alice'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.partition()`:

```
result = Path(url).stem.partition('.')[0]
```